# Regex to capture text with unknown number of repeated groups in between

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy, capture-group

I'm trying to parse the number that follows "Dining:" in the following text, under SECOND LEVEL. So '666' should be returned.

```
    MAIN LEVEL
        Entrance: 11
        Dining: 33

    SECOND LEVEL
        Entrance: 4444
        Living: 5555
        Dining: 666

    THIRD LEVEL
        Dining: 999
        Kitchen: 000
        Family: 33332
```

If I use something like `(?:\bDining:\s)(.*\b)` then it captures the first occurrence under MAIN. I'm trying to therefore specify `SECOND LEVEL` in the regex, followed by a repeating pattern of: new lines, multiple spaces, and then any text, until `Dining:` is found. [This demo](https://regex101.com/r/cP3zS6/1) illustrates the two problems I encounter. The regex used is: `(?:\bSECOND\sLEVEL(\n\s+.*)*Dining:)(.*\b)`

1. A "Catastrophic backtracking" error appears **until** you delete the very last line containing `Laundry: 1`. Is this caused by too many matches or something?
2. Once you delete that line, the regex captures only the **last** match under `OTHER LEVEL` .. returning '2' as opposed to the match under `SECOND LEVEL`.

Sometimes `Dining:` will not exist under `SECOND LEVEL` and therefore nothing should be returned.

What is a  regex that will only capture the `SECOND LEVEL`'s `Dining:` number, and if it doesn't exist then returns nothing? Straight up regex preferred, no looping in Java if possible. Thanks

Comment: I'm curious about the requirement for "no Java code."  Are you using a framework or is that simply your own personal preference?

Comment: Good question. I'm simply trying to remain consistent since a lot of my other text extraction involves regex, so I was hoping to avoid using loops or something for one part of the extraction process, and pure regex for another. Perhaps that's dumb though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead based regex.

```
"(?m)^\\s*\\bSECOND LEVEL\\n(?:(?!\\n\\n)[\\s\\S])*\\bDining:\\s*(\\d+)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nD3gG5/1)

Comment: That works great, thank you. I've read the explanation but am confused what the regex is saying. Is it saying: "look ahead to ensure two newlines never exist in sequence (representing a change in LEVELS), followed by the literal match of `Dining:` ...?  Either way, thank you

Comment: ya, it ensures that there isn't a blank line present inbetween the `second level` and `dining` strings.

Answer (score 1):

The best example I know of for catastrophic backtracking [from here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) is `(x+x+)+y`. That is to say,  it cannot work out the correct boundaries for the capture groups containing x because there are too many ways to divide them.

xxxxy is the first two + once, the third twice,  or each of the first twice and the third once,  or either of the first thrice, the other once and the last once.  As you can see that gets dangerous!

You had `(?:\bSECOND\sLEVEL(\n\s+.*)*Dining:)(.*\b)` note the `(\n\s+.*)*`
 the `.*` can be a nightmare when combined with the previous `\n\s` and enclosed with a `*`.  It should be rewritten `(\n\s+[^\s\n][^\n]*)*` this ensures each quantifier ends before the next begins,  minimising backtracking.

With this kind of thinking in mind I came up with the following regex to match your string:

```
(?<=SECOND LEVEL\n)(?:\s+(?:[^\s\n:][^\n:]*):[^\n]*)*\s+Dining:\s*([^\s\n][^\n$]*)
```

Comment: Looks great! Thank you. I'm inclined to go with the other answer due to his reputation, and seemingly cleaner/shorter regex. No doubt I'm going to study your solution now though to understand. Thanks for taking the time.